# IOS Team Provisioning Profile - Pending (Managed by Xcode)

Tags: xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

In my project in Xcode I have Issue: "No non-expired provisioning profiles are installed". 
I clicked "Fix Issue" and after 2-3 minutes:

"Generation of the team provisioning profile Apple ID "XxXxXxXxXx" is still pending. Please wait a moment and then click the Refresh button in the Details section of the Accounts tab fot this team."

I refreshed it and nothing. I have still "Pending (Managed by Xcode)" in all "IOS Team Provisioning Profile" on https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/profile/profileList.action.

any idea to fix it?

Comment: You have to play the waiting game, I'm afraid. It's usually fairly instant, but I have seen it take a couple of hours once. (sorry!)

Comment: I hope there is another way than waiting many hours ... This is probably a communication error xcode with https://developer.apple.com

Comment: Seems like the service might be down... again: https://discussions.apple.com/message/24786001

Comment: same problem here, i have been waiting for about an hour

Comment: Have any body resloved this issue...

Comment: There is only one way: waiting... :(

Comment: Have all you checked if there is any pending terms or agreements to read and accept on your accounts? Are your accounts valid and the payment ok?

Comment: Yes of course I checked it!

Comment: After four hours, everything has been repaired.

Answer (score 4):

You can manually create your own provisioning profile (NOT managed by Xcode) and use that instead until the Xcode-managed profile is approved.

I have spent 24 hours with an Xcode profile in the "Pending" state, but if I manually create one it seems to get approved instantly.

You can manually add profiles through the Apple Developer Portal at https://developer.apple.com. You can use a wildcard app ID (*) to match any app, the same as your Xcode profile uses.

Answer (score 2):

Generating a provisioning profile can take some time and there isn't much you can do about it once it's "Pending" on the iOS developer center. In some instances, you may have to wait up to a few hours for the profile to be ready.

Answer (score 1):

For those who dont want to wait but need a provisioning profile for app with any bundle id. Create new wildcard App ID in the portal. Then create new provision profile and select your new wildcard App ID, then download and install. It's work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have Xcode 5.1 and i fixed the issue like this

Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> View details -> Refresh button (Bottom Left)

After it was refreshed i clicked done, and the error was gone :)